# When does a DOM-Element belong to the DOM-tree

Tags: javascript, dom

i am recently doing some DOM tests so I came to a problem i couldn't find a clear answer to yet. When you create a DOM-Element using document.createElement(...) but you don't append it to the DOM via e.g [ElementInDom].appendChild(...). Is this DOM-Element handled like a variable like any other String or array etc. in Javascript, or does the document handle access to the DOM-Element even before it is added to the DOM?

I have wrote a small test which does show that access to a DOM-Element not attached to the DOM is faster than access to a DOM-Element attached to the document (and not rendered by setting it to display: none). But asking to be sure. It's on purpose I only put it to the DOM-tree and not to the Render-tree.

Test is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mz18jdth/)

```
<html>
<body>

<ul style="display:none;"></ul>

<script>
    var inDOM = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    var noDOM = document.createElement('ul');
    var array = [];

    var start1 = new Date();

    for (var i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        inDOM.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    };

    var end1 = new Date() - start1;

    var start2 = new Date();

    for (var i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
            noDOM.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
    };

    var end2 = new Date() - start2;

    var start3 = new Date();

    for (var i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        array[i] = document.createElement('li');
    };

    var end3 = new Date() - start3;

    console.log('in DOM: ' + end1);
    console.log('not in DOM: ' + end2);
    console.log('to Array: ' + end3);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It only becomes part of the DOM once appended to the document or its children, otherwise it is just like any other object with methods that is assigned to a variable. I think that is all you are actually asking?

Answer (score 2):

Every DOM element is represented as an object in JavaScript, whether it is in the document or not. The difference between a DOM element in the document and a DOM element *not* in the document is the effect that mutations to the DOM element have.

If the DOM element is not in the document, it cannot impact the current view and thus the browser does not have to perform reflows if you mutate it. Reflows are expensive, so *not* having to do them is faster.

A DOM element is in the document if there is a path from the element to the document root (`document.documentElement`).

Comment: Better clarification than my comment.

Comment: Ah okay, but whats with an DOM-Element appended to the document but with display set to none. Than it's in the Document(DOM-tree) but not in the render-tree, but like my tests say it seems to have an impact on access to the element but it couldn't have impact the current view and thus the browser because its not performing reflows.

Comment: Good point. I'm not sure, I'd assume that the browser still has to perform some other bookkeeping. Or maybe it computes some styles (such as color) preemptively in case the parent becomes visible.